# how to skip protected cells in a range and write data to it using Excel COM Interop?

Tags: vb.net, excel

Can anyone please advise how to write a 2D array into an excel range (skipping protected cells).

I'm using following code for doing that but getting exception since the range has protected cells.

```
Public Sub WriteData(cell1 As String, cell2 As String, data As String(,))
    Dim range As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range
    range = wrkSheet.Range(cell1, cell2)
    range.Value2 = data
End Sub
```

Regards
Dinesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead having one range (entire sheet) with protected cells, I have split the entire worksheet into separate ranges (such that it wont have protected cells) and wrote data into those ranges using 2D object arrays.

Comment: The above method has drastic improvement in performance. It used to take 60 sec to write 27000 cells. If we use ranges and 2D object arrays it took 6 sec for the same job, which is a lot quicker.